# SignalR javascript client not picking up event from hub

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

I have a method on the hub however I am not getting any messages from this.  I get the connection ID's from my user to connectionid mapping dictionary and loop through these connectionid's and then invoke a method on the client side called `deviceDiscovered`  I can also confirm that the browser does connect to the hub

Here is my hub method

```
public async Task DetectDevice(dynamic message)
    {
        //We will be searching via the userid
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        //now we get the connectionID from the table.
        var connectionObj = ConnectionTable[connectionId];

        //we now check whether this is a pathfinder or browser client
        if (connectionObj.clientType == "pathfinder")
        {
            /*The pathfinder initiated the request and so this means the message should be forwarded to the browser client
             that requested this resource*/

            //Grab the data out of the dictionary.
            PathfinderDetection deviceDiscoveredNotification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PathfinderDetection>(message);
            var userId = deviceDiscoveredNotification.userId;
            var sysInfo = deviceDiscoveredNotification.sysInfo;
            var found = deviceDiscoveredNotification.data;

            if (found == "FOUND")
            {
                var deviceId = deviceDiscoveredNotification.deviceID;

                var connections = ConnectionTable.Where(val => val.Value.id == connectionObj.id).Select(key => key.Key).ToList();
                foreach (string connection in connections)
                {
                    Clients.Client(connection).deviceDiscovered(deviceId);
                }


            }
            else
            {

                //call a method on client side.
                Clients.Group(userId.ToString()).noDevice("NOTFOUND");
            }
```

I can see that the deviceID variable is populated and that the connection exists, however not getting anything back from the hub when looking at the client

here is my client side code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:59016");
    var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('metrics');

    contosoChatHubProxy.on('taskAdded', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });

    contosoChatHubProxy.on('deviceDiscovered', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    contosoChatHubProxy.on('taskUpdate', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });




    contosoChatHubProxy.on('noDevice', function(found) {
        console.log(found);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, can you slim down the code to only show what's relevant?

Comment: Yes mark, just sometimes people ask for more code, so thought I would put the methods that are relevant,  I can slim down the JS

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. In this case though it would help slimming down a little